# After a specific time of day - which method is better?

Tags: sql-server

I need to know (and label) whether a particular event in a subquery happens after 3:30 PM (regardless of the date).
With my setup, I haven't been able to determine by trial which is more efficient (they come back too quickly) and the execution plan isn't helpful.

The second (#2) seems more efficient to me because the literal only needs to be cast once (leaving one operation per row).
However, sometimes operations like this are deceiving, so I was hoping that someone could tell me which is better.

```
CREATE TABLE #jccTestData([ProcessDate] datetime);
INSERT INTO #jccTestData ([ProcessDate])
VALUES 
    ('2019-03-12 10:23:28.000') ,('2019-03-17 11:22:40.000'), ('2019-03-18 11:25:30.000')
    ,('2019-03-19 11:42:02.000') ,('2019-03-11 12:45:30.000') ,('2019-03-12 13:14:20.000')
    ,('2019-03-13 15:20:13.000') ,('2019-03-14 15:29:40.000') ,('2019-03-15 15:29:59.997') 
    ,('2019-03-16 15:30:00.000') ,('2019-03-17 15:30:00.003') ,('2019-03-18 16:25:30.000')
    ,('2019-03-12 23:59:59.997') ,('2019-03-13 00:00:00.003') ,('2019-03-14 00:00:00.000')
    ,('2019-03-15 03:14:20.000') ,('2019-03-16 05:20:13.000')

SELECT 
    [ProcessDate]
    , Case When datepart(HH, [ProcessDate]) > 15
        OR (datepart(HH, [ProcessDate]) = 15 And datepart(n, [ProcessDate]) >= 30) 
        Then 'After 3:30 PM' 
        End As [After 3:30? #1]
    , Case When cast([ProcessDate] As time) >= cast('15:30:00' As time) 
        Then 'After 3:30 PM' 
        End As [After 3:30? #2]
FROM #jccTestData  
ORDER BY [ProcessDate]

DROP TABLE #jccTestData
```

The second one also seems more maintainable.

If there's a third option I'm open to that also.
SQL Server 2012+

Comment: It doesn't make much difference. This is a column in the result so indexing isn't an issue here. But you should not order by ordinal position, it can cause all sorts of problems if you query changes.

Comment: @SeanLange True. Sloppy of me to set a bad example, even with test code.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, if you can, I would actually add a computed column to your table. `CONVERT`/`CAST` to the `time` data type is definitely the way to go if using that route, but if you can add a persisted computed column then you can index that column, or add it to your existing ones, and maintain SARGability if you ever need to query this data in the `WHERE` (I realise the sample here is a temporary table, but i doubt the real scenario is):

```
ALTER TABLE #jccTestData ADD ProcessTime AS CONVERT(time,ProcessDate) PERSISTED;
```

Then you can just query that new column:

```
SELECT [ProcessDate],
       CASE WHEN ProcessTime >= '03:30' THEN 'After 3:30 PM' END AS [After 3:30?]
FROM #jccTestData
ORDER BY [ProcessDate];
```

Also, avoid using ordinal numbers for columns in the `ORDER BY`, you are far better off using the columns actual name.

*Side note, you don't need to have a column for casting/converting to the `date` datatype. `CONVERT(date,ProcessDate)` and `CAST(ProcessDate AS date)` are both SARGable.*

Comment: Changing the schema isn't an option at this time, but thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: I'm drawing a blank on your use of the word "SARG" (SARGability & SARGable). Can you inform/remind me what that stands for?

Comment: @J.ChrisCompton https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-sargable-expressions-in-t-sql-queries-performance-advantages-and-examples/

Comment: If a query is SARGable it means that the `WHERE` contains Searchable ARGuments than can be used against an index. Something like `WHERE CONVERT(time,ProcessDate) > '03:30'` isn't SARGable, as the `CONVERT` changes the ordering of the column `ProcessDate`, meaning that indexing can't be used. Even so, just because an expression doesn't change the ordering, doesn't make it SARGable. [Define: SARGable](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+SARGable).

Comment: [Sargable Functions](https://datatellblog.wordpress.com/2016/11/24/sql-server-query-optimization-sargable-functions/)

Comment: I see, thanks!  FYI: The innermost part of the *real query* has a covered where clause. The "After 3:30" computed column is in addition to the process date (for all values in the date range).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking about efficiency, I did some benchmarks on more than a million real records.  The last method (CAST) as below reports more CPU time.  All times were in milliseconds, so you would need millions of records to notice any difference.

```
IIF((DATEPART(HH, dateStamp) * 60) + DATEPART(MINUTE, dateStamp) >= 930, 'After 3:30 PM', '')
IIF(DATEPART(HH, dateStamp) > 15 OR (DATEPART(HH, dateStamp) = 15 AND DATEPART(N, dateStamp) >= 30), 'After 3:30 PM', '')
IIF(CAST(dateStamp AS TIME) >= CAST('15:30:00' AS TIME), 'After 3:30 PM', '')
```

1) Average CPU time: 477; Average Elapsed time: 242

2) Average CPU time: 469; Average Elapsed time: 236

3) Average CPU time: 808; Average Elapsed time: 413

Comment: "For a few million rows, there's virtually no difference."  thanks, that covers the question.  Interesting that the cast is more CPU than the multiplication.  I'd give you another +1 if I could for the conversion to minutes, which I should have thought of myself.

Comment: The CAST method has more than 25% performance difference when I attempted to reduce other contingencies, so I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

I would use third option which is `apply` if you are really don't change the `DB` structure :

```
SELECT d.[ProcessDate],
       (CASE WHEN dd.ProcessTime >= '15:30' THEN 'After 3:30 PM' END) AS [After 3:30?]
FROM #jccTestData d CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES (CONVERT(TIME, ProcessDate)) 
     ) dd (ProcessTime )
ORDER BY d.[ProcessDate];
```